# ¿Cómo importar mi módulo a mi código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo pruebas de animaciones con CDN y diferentes códigos, en esta ocasión me sale este error al querer exportar mi código desde mi `style.css`:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

Ya verifiqué nombres de etiquetas y todo esta de acuerdo a lo estipulado, si tienen algunos tips para poder hacer el código funcional se los agradecería muchísimo.

Código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.8.1/lottie.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>FIESTA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>
      !FIESTA!
      <div class="svg"></div>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
import "./style.css";

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const svgContainer = document.querySelector('.svg');

const animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    wrapper: svgContainer,
    animType: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path:"https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_obhph3sh.json"
})

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    animation.goToAndPlay(0,true);
});
```

Comment: Hola! Para qué necesitas importar el archivo css en el script?

Comment: ***querer exportar mi codigo desde mi style.css*** ¿A qué te refieres con **exportar**? En CSS no hay (hasta donde yo conozco) tal funcionalidad. ¿Será que estás usando algún tipo de bundler como Webpack o algo por el estilo?

Answer (score 0):

Como lo mencionan en uno de los comentarios deberás estar usando Webpack, en especifico los siguientes loaders:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/
En la documentación menciona como deberás hacer la importación

Answer (score 0):

para poder usar import tienes que llamar el javascript con el attributo type="module"

```
<script type="module">
  import "./style.css";
  // ...
  // ...
</script>
```

si tu codigo estuviera en el archivo app.js lo llamarias asi

```
<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Además, para que esto funcione, la página debe ser servida desde un servidor, mediante `http` o `https`, los módulos no funcionan en un entorno local (`file://`).